# Messages duplicates twice when a user sends a message

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm building a chat application that sends messages and media files, my problem is that when a user sends a message or a media file it displays twice. But when I close my chat activity and open it again it displays as expected i.e. once.

**My Chat Activity**

```
public class ChatActivityy extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        messageSenderID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        Rootref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

        messageReceiverID = getIntent().getExtras().get("visit_user_id").toString();
        messageReceiverName = getIntent().getExtras().get("visit_user_name").toString();

        //Toast.makeText(this, messageReceiverID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Toast.makeText(this, messageReceiverName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        InitializeControllers();
        DisplayLastSeen();
        GetUserInfo();
        userName.setText(messageReceiverName);

        SendMessageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                notify = true;
                SendMessage();
                //MessageInputText.setText("");
            }
        });

        SendFilesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CharSequence[] options = new CharSequence[]
                        {
                                "Images",
                                "Videos",
                                "Documents",
                                "Audio",
                                "Cancel"
                        };
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ChatActivityy.this);
                builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            checker = "image";

                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                            intent.setType("image/*");
                            startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image"), 438);
                        }
}
                });
                builder.show();
            }
        });
        apiService = Client.getClient("https://fcm.googleapis.com/").create(APIService.class);
    }    
}
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 438 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null & data.getData() !=null)
        {
            loadingBar.setTitle("Sending file");
            loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait, your file is sending");
            loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            loadingBar.show();

            fileUri = data.getData();
if(checker.equals("image"))
            {
                StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Image Files");

                String messageSenderRef = "Messages/" + messageSenderID + "/" + messageReceiverID;
                String messageReceiverRef = "Messages/" + messageReceiverID + "/" + messageSenderID;

                DatabaseReference userMessageKeyRef = Rootref.child("Messages")
                        .child(messageSenderID).child(messageReceiverID).push();

                final String messagePushID = userMessageKeyRef.getKey();

                final StorageReference filepath = storageReference.child(messagePushID + "." + "jpg");

                uploadTask = filepath.putFile(fileUri);

                uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation() {
                    @Override
                    public Object then(@NonNull Task task) throws Exception {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            throw task.getException();
                        }
                        return filepath.getDownloadUrl();
                    }
                }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            Uri downloadUrl = task.getResult();
                            myUrl = downloadUrl.toString();

                            Map messageTextBody = new HashMap();
                            messageTextBody.put("message", myUrl);
                            messageTextBody.put("name", fileUri.getLastPathSegment());
                            messageTextBody.put("type", checker);
                            messageTextBody.put("from", messageSenderID);
                            messageTextBody.put("to", messageReceiverID);
                            messageTextBody.put("messageID", messagePushID);
                            messageTextBody.put("time", saveCurrentTime);
                            messageTextBody.put("date", saveCurrentDate);

                            Map messageBodyDetails = new HashMap();
                            messageBodyDetails.put(messageSenderRef + "/" + messagePushID, messageTextBody);
                            messageBodyDetails.put(messageReceiverRef + "/" + messagePushID, messageTextBody);

                            Rootref.updateChildren(messageBodyDetails).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                                        // Toast.makeText(ChatActivityy.this, "Message Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    } else {
                                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                                        Toast.makeText(ChatActivityy.this, "Message not sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                    MessageInputText.setText("");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                loadingBar.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(this, "No Image Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
 @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Rootref.child("Messages").child(messageSenderID).child(messageReceiverID)
                .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                        Messages messages = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
                        messagesList.add(messages);
                        messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        userMessagesList.smoothScrollToPosition(userMessagesList.getAdapter().getItemCount());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
    }
 private void SendMessage()
    {
        String messageText = MessageInputText.getText().toString();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(messageText))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Enter a Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            String messageSenderRef = "Messages/" + messageSenderID + "/" + messageReceiverID;
            String messageReceiverRef = "Messages/" + messageReceiverID + "/" + messageSenderID;

            DatabaseReference userMessageKeyRef = Rootref.child("Messages")
                    .child(messageSenderID).child(messageReceiverID).push();

            String messagePushID = userMessageKeyRef.getKey();

            Map messageTextBody = new HashMap();
            messageTextBody.put("message", messageText);
            messageTextBody.put("type", "text");
            messageTextBody.put("from", messageSenderID);
            messageTextBody.put("to", messageReceiverID);
            messageTextBody.put("messageID", messagePushID);
            messageTextBody.put("time", saveCurrentTime);
            messageTextBody.put("date", saveCurrentDate);

            Map messageBodyDetails = new HashMap();
            messageBodyDetails.put(messageSenderRef + "/" + messagePushID, messageTextBody);
            messageBodyDetails.put(messageReceiverRef + "/" + messagePushID, messageTextBody);

            Rootref.updateChildren(messageBodyDetails).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                       // Toast.makeText(ChatActivityy.this, "Message Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(ChatActivityy.this, "Message not sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    MessageInputText.setText("");
                }
            });
            final String msg = messageText;

           // UsersRef.child(messageSenderID);
            UsersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Friends user = dataSnapshot.getValue(Friends.class);
                    if (notify) {
                        sendNotification(messageReceiverID, user.getName(), msg);
                    }
                    notify = false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**My Adapter**

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.MessageViewHolder>
{
    private List<Messages> userMessagesList;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference usersRef;

    MessageAdapter(List<Messages> userMessagesList) {
        this.userMessagesList = userMessagesList;
    }

    class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView senderMessageText, receiverMessageText;
        ZoomageView senderImage, receiverImage;
        ImageView senderMedia, receiverMedia;


        public MessageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            senderMessageText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sender_message_text);
            receiverMessageText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.receiver_message_text);

        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.custom_messages_layout, parent, false);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        return new MessageViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MessageViewHolder messageViewHolder, final int position) {
        String messageSenderID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        final Messages messages = userMessagesList.get(position);

        String fromUserID = messages.getFrom();
        String fromMessageType = messages.getType();

        usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(fromUserID);
        messageViewHolder.receiverMessageText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        messageViewHolder.senderMessageText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (fromMessageType.equals("text")) {
            if (fromUserID.equals(messageSenderID)) {
                messageViewHolder.senderMessageText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                messageViewHolder.senderMessageText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sender_message);
                messageViewHolder.senderMessageText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                messageViewHolder.senderMessageText.setText(messages.getMessage() + "\n \n" + messages.getTime() + " - " + messages.getDate());
            } else {
                messageViewHolder.receiverMessageText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          messageViewHolder.receiverMessageText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.receiver_messages_layout);
                messageViewHolder.receiverMessageText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                messageViewHolder.receiverMessageText.setText(messages.getMessage() + "\n \n" + messages.getTime() + " - " + messages.getDate());
            }
        }


        if (fromUserID.equals(messageSenderID))
        {
            messageViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (userMessagesList.get(position).getType().equals("text"))
                    {
                        CharSequence[] options = new CharSequence[]
                                {
                                        "Delete for me",
                                        "Delete for Everyone",
                                        "Copy",
                                        "Cancel"
                                };
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(messageViewHolder.itemView.getContext());

                        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                                if (i == 0)
                                {
                                    deleteSentMessage(position, messageViewHolder);
                                }
                                else if (i == 1)
                                {
                                    deleteMessageForEveryone(position, messageViewHolder);
                                }

                                else if (i == 2)
                                {
                                    ClipboardManager myClipboard = (ClipboardManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

                                    ClipData myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", messageViewHolder.senderMessageText.getText().toString());
                                    myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);
                                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Copied to clipboard" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

                                    //setClipboard(mContext, messageViewHolder.senderMessageText.toString());
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        builder.show();
                    }
                  }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return userMessagesList.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comments but @Teempy already answered my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be because you attach a listener in onStart. After you start a new intent, the activity is paused, and then, after the user has added a new message and resumed the old activity, method onStart is called one more time. So at that moment you have two listeners. If the next added message is duplicated three times, then it must be the actual problem. Try moving EventListener to onCreate. Or check if it is already assigned to your directory (Idk if this is possible with the database), if you want to leave it in onStart

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly!